# How to get new column data from varchar column

Tags: sql, sybase

I got help to get select query to get the correct data, but how can I insert this into table.

Following

```
Select RIGHT(RTRIM(Template_name), 2) country
from TABLE
```

This gets for me following:
Example data:

```
Template_name            Country
Party_package_US         US 
PARTY_Package_GB         GB 
Random_temp_DE           DE
```

But the main question is how can I insert into table where template_name exists and add only the country initials to new column.

Link for earlier question where I got help: [how to get info from VARCHAR column and create new column out of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476054/how-to-get-info-from-varchar-column-and-create-new-column-out-of-it/35476666?noredirect=1#comment58662993_35476666)

I figured that I could do subselect that inserts right form to new column

```
UPDATE #silverpop_header
SET MARKET_AREA = a.template_name
FROM  #silverpop_header pop
join dw.f_CRM a
ON   pop.template_name = a.TEMPLATE_NAME
left join (
select 
RIGHT(RTRIM(Template_name), 2) country
from dw.f_CRM )
```

But I think I have done this wrong somehow

Comment: I'd consider using triggers to make sure consistent data is inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But the main question is how can I insert into table where template_name exists and add only the country initials to new column.

Please find the below script to perform the operation based on your comment mentioned above :

```
update silverpop_header set MARKET_AREA = (Select RIGHT(RTRIM(Template_name), 2) country from silverpop_header a where a.TEMPLATE_NAME = 'Party_package_US');
```

This will update the record for Party_package_US template. If you want to perform for all the templates then you have to write a simple cursor to read all template_name and execute the same update query for each template.

Update me if anything is required.

Find the cursor below which has been written for SQLServer.

```
DECLARE @TAMPLATENAME VARCHAR(100), @SQL VARCHAR(500), @quotes varchar(4)
DECLARE UPDATE_COUNTRIES CURSOR FOR SELECT TEMPLATE_NAME FROM silverpop_header
set @quotes = '''';
OPEN UPDATE_COUNTRIES
FETCH NEXT FROM UPDATE_COUNTRIES INTO @TAMPLATENAME
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @SQL = 'update silverpop_header set MARKET_AREA = (Select RIGHT(RTRIM(Template_name), 2) country from silverpop_header a where a.TEMPLATE_NAME = '+@quotes+@TAMPLATENAME+@quotes+' ) where TEMPLATE_NAME = '+@quotes+@TAMPLATENAME+@quotes
print(@SQL)
EXEC(@SQL)
FETCH NEXT FROM UPDATE_COUNTRIES INTO @TAMPLATENAME
END
CLOSE UPDATE_COUNTRIES
DEALLOCATE UPDATE_COUNTRIES
```

Comment: What if I have 1000 templates, then how can I do this as one task?

Comment: That is great, but I have to use update query  and I don't have rights to access SQL server :/

Comment: yes you can add a.Template_name is not null in the dynamic query. Which will look something like below query - SET @SQL = 'update silverpop_header set MARKET_AREA = (Select RIGHT(RTRIM(Template_name), 2) country from silverpop_header a where a.TEMPLATE_NAME is not null and a.TEMPLATE_NAME = '+@quotes+@TAMPLATENAME+@quotes+' ) where TEMPLATE_NAME = '+@quotes+@TAMPLATENAME+@quotes

Comment: Above cursor has been written for SQLServer. You can write cursor for your own database which will be similar to above with some changes in syntax's.

Comment: I found a great problem. After adding query with subquery then procedure gave me an error.. Can you help me with that one?

Comment: sure, please forward your procedure, I will have a look on it.

Comment: update silverpop_header 
set TEMPLATE_NAME = (Select RIGHT(RTRIM(TEMPLATE_NAME), 3) Market_area
from silverpop_header a
where a.TEMPLATE_NAME is not NULL )

Comment: Could not execute statement.
Subquery cardinality violation, >1 row returned from a subquery
--(dfo_subQfiler.cxx 2701) SQLCODE= -1001022, ODBC 3 State="HY000"
Line 2 Column 1

Comment: boss, your subquery((Select RIGHT(RTRIM(TEMPLATE_NAME), 3) Market_area from silverpop_header a where a.TEMPLATE_NAME is not NULL )) is returning more than one result that's why the problem is coming. your are not using my update query which has the condition to check the template_name(a.TEMPLATE_NAME = '+@quotes+@TAMPLATENAME+@quotes+' ). Please prefer the update query that i provided to you. if you miss to provide template name in where clause then the subquery will process all the records.

Answer (score 0):

The final result that worked is following:

```
update #temp_table
    set veerg2 = RIGHT(RTRIM(nimi), 3)  
    from #temp_table a 
    where a.nimi is not NULL ;
```

Just cuting out select on the SET part did the trick